# Select2 JQuery Select Boxes insert text option

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2

In a recent search to find an AJAX enabled, typeahead, rich HTML based select box alternative, I ran across the JQuery based Select2 (http://ivaynberg.github.com/select2/), and have found it to be a great alternative.

One thing I didn't find extremely well done however, was the documentation  about the option to type values into the text box of the select2 plugin that do not appear in the select list.

I have read this post: [Entering values into a jquery-select2 that are not in the select list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16513611/entering-values-into-a-jquery-select2-that-are-not-in-the-select-list) but it doesn´t help me.

Any help or information about it will be really apreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

try adding this to your $opts initialization:

```
    //Allow manually entered text in drop down.
    createSearchChoice: function(term, data) {
        if ( $(data).filter( function() {
            return this.text.localeCompare(term) === 0;
        }).length === 0) {
            return {id:term, text:term};
        }
    },
```