# How to enter free text inside Select2 component?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-select2

I am using JQuery Select2 component (see here: http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/ ) but I have problem configuring it so it would serve dual purpose - as autosuggest for matching data but also as a text box for new entries.  Can someone help me configure that component correctly, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are looking for the Tagging option:

[Select2 Tags documentation](http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/#tags)

It will allow you to set up your own data to match to but accepts custom inputs.

```
$("#e20").select2({               
    tags:["red", "green", "blue"],              
    tokenSeparators: [",", " "]
});
```

Comment: That will look really odd if you only want one item I'd suggest you use this instead: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14577014/select2-dropdown-but-allow-new-values-by-user

Answer (score 3):

Instead of

```
$('#name').select2();
```

You can try to use this:

```
$('#name').select2({
    multiple: false,
    tags: true,
    createTag: function (tag) {
        return {id: tag.term, text: tag.term, tag: true};
    }
});
```