# Select2: How to allow user to select from a default list but accept a new string?

Tags: javascript, jquery-select2

I've this need, and I'm not able to accomplish it using Select2.

User must choose a name from a list. This list is a well-defined list of strings. So I think to pass this list as 'data' to Select2.

If user wants, he can choose a new name, and it must be accepted without problem, without saying and asking nothing to user.

So I tried to use an INPUT as element, using data: to feed default list, and to user createSearchChoice to return a new object with id: term,  text: term

But I got

> query function not defined for Select2 OrdiniCaricati_Nome_Cliente

What's the right combination on properties / element / functions to use?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Select2 dropdown but allow new values by user?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14577014/select2-dropdown-but-allow-new-values-by-user)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A similar question can be found over here: [Select2 dropdown but allow new values bu user?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14577014/select2-dropdown-but-allow-new-values-by-user?rq=1)

Here is a working JSFiddle I found between the answers: http://jsfiddle.net/pHSdP/2/

HTML

```
<input type='hidden' id='tags' style='width:300px'/>
```

JQuery

```
$("#tags").select2({
createSearchChoice:function(term, data) { if ($(data).filter(function() { return this.text.localeCompare(term)===0; }).length===0) {return {id:term, text:term};} },
multiple: false,
data: [{id: 0, text: 'story'},{id: 1, text: 'bug'},{id: 2, text: 'task'}]
});
```