# Yii Booster Select2 - allow new values

Tags: javascript, php, yii, jquery-select2

I am using Select2 from Yii Booster as dropdown list. I would like to allow user to enter his own value, but I do not know how. I think, there is no configuration for this. I think I might try something like here - [Select2 dropdown but allow new values by user?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14577014/select2-dropdown-but-allow-new-values-by-user) but I do not know how to add this javascript when rendering select2 from php form. Could anyone help? Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can add a javascript function as a option in the widget's options by prefixing it with 'js:', for example:

```
$this->widget(
    'booster.widgets.TbSelect2',
    array(
        'asDropDownList' => false,
        'name' => 'clevertech',
        'options' => array(
            'tags' => array('clever', 'is', 'better', 'clevertech'),
            'placeholder' => 'type clever, or is, or just type!',
            'width' => '40%',
            'tokenSeparators' => array(',', ' ')
            'createSearchChoice' => 'js:function(term, data) {
             if ( $(data).filter( function() {
               return this.text.localeCompare(term)===0;
             }).length===0) {
               return {id:term, text:term};
             }',
           }
        )
    )
);
```

For further debugging, if you open TbSelect2.php you can see what it does with the options:

```
$options = !empty($this->options) ? CJavaScript::encode($this->options) : '';
```

And if you go to CJavaScript::encode function you can see it does:

```
if(is_string($value))
{
    if(strpos($value,'js:')===0 && $safe===false)
        return substr($value,3);
    else
        return "'".self::quote($value)."'";
}
```

Note: I've opened CJavaScript::encode of Yii 1 not 2 but might be the same.

Comment: Thank you for reply. This would probably work, but i am getting error "'createSearchChoice' is not allowed for Select2 when attached to a <select> element." Yii is probably appliing select2 on select not input element :(

Comment: by the way I am using asDropDownList true

Comment: I ran into a similar problem with custom select2 options that did not allow me to use a dropdown, so I have switched to a hidden input, doesn't it work if you set asDropDownList to false? from what I can see in the code it will use a hidden field.

Comment: Yes, it works when you set asDropDownList to false, but I wanted to use it as DropDownList. Never mind, I use it in tagging mode now and it is ok:-) How did you switched to hidden input?

Comment: I was using select2 plugin alone without this extension, so I had just generated a hidden field with a ID and applied select2 to that ID.