# Select 2 version 4.0 allow user to enter free text

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2, jquery-select2-4

I am using the latest version of Select2: [Select2 4.0](https://select2.github.io).

I would like to allow users to enter free text. In other words if a user cannot find a option in the drop down (data returned by ajax), I want them to be able to 'select' whatever text they have typed in.

This is my markup:

```
<select class="required form-control" id="businessName" data-placeholder="Choose An Name" > </select>
```

And this is the JavaScript that I am using to initialize Select2:

```
$("#businessName").select2({
    ajax: {
      url: "/register/namelookup",
      dataType: 'json',
      delay: 250,
      type: 'post',
      data: function (params) {
        return {
          businessName: params.term, // search term
          page: params.page
        };
      },
      processResults: function (data, page) {
        return {
          results: data.items
        };
      },
      cache: false
    },
    escapeMarkup: function (markup) { return markup; },
    minimumInputLength: 4,
    createSearchChoice:function(term, data) {
        if ( $(data).filter( function() {
          return this.text.localeCompare(term)===0;
        }).length===0) {
          return {id:term, text:term};
        }
    },
});
```

I added `createSearchChoice` but it doesn't work.  I have looked at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14577014/select2-dropdown-but-allow-new-values-by-user) as well but so far no luck.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Select2 dropdown but allow new values by user?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14577014/select2-dropdown-but-allow-new-values-by-user)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

This was a change in 4.0.0 that resulted from undocumented behaviour in 3.x. In 3.x, if you were using `createSearchChoice` you also *should have* been using `tags` (setting it to `true` or an empty array). This is because `createSearchChoice` and `tags` were tied together.

In 4.x, `createSearchChoice` was renamed to `createTag` because it was really creating the tag. This was documented in the [4.0.0-beta.2 release notes](https://github.com/select2/select2/releases/tag/4.0.0-beta.2). Additionally, the second (also undocumented) parameter to `createSearchChoice` was never implemented - but you don't actually need it in this case.

So, with those two changes noted, the working code to allow for new options to be added by the user is

```
$("#businessName").select2({
    ajax: {
      url: "/register/namelookup",
      dataType: 'json',
      delay: 250,
      type: 'post',
      data: function (params) {
        return {
          businessName: params.term, // search term
          page: params.page
        };
      },
      processResults: function (data, page) {
        return {
          results: data.items
        };
      },
      cache: false
    },
    escapeMarkup: function (markup) { return markup; },
    minimumInputLength: 4,
    tags: true
});
```

Notice that I did not implement `createTag`, this is because [the default implementation](https://github.com/select2/select2/blob/ac1680d81dcc60009c5d0fe0dd52e70bc065c140/src/js/select2/data/tags.js#L87-L98) matched what your old `createSearchChoice` was trying to do. I did add `tags: true` though, because that is still required in order to make it work.

On top of that, you do have some invalid markup now that you have changed to a `<select>`.

```
<select class="required form-control" id="businessName" data-placeholder="Choose An Name" ></select>
```

The `type` attribute (previously set to `hidden`) is only required if you are using an `<input />` and is not valid on a `<select>`. This shouldn't make any noticeable change to you.

Comment: Hi Kevin, thank you very much for your extensive answer, I should have spent more time on reading the release notes. Now it's working fine.

Comment: Thank you I was sitting here like a berk wondering what was going on using code that worked in my last app before realising I was using the new version of select2.

Comment: @kevin-brown, would you mind suggesting how to remove some of the free text after it's been added through `createSearchChoice`? I created a new question here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/39784421/1299792

Comment: Some additions: If you are using templateResult or templateSelection as options, you have to keep in mind to check index.text. All added select options with createTag are structured as {id: '', text: ''}. If your are creating a template and using other than item.text, the new select option will not set to the select.

Comment: If I create a tag with free text, when I next select an existing option from the same select then my selected free text tag is removed from the selected options.