# Select2 in Xpages Cannot add new value: Error is "Validation Error: value is not valid"

Tags: xpages, jquery-select2-4

I am using Select2 (4.0) in an XPage. I have a ComboBox whose value is tied to a property in a bean, and the select items are populated (for now) by a viewScope variable I populate in before page load.

The user is able to type in a new value, but when I go to save the data I am getting a validation error:

[image]

This is not a validation error that I wrote but from Xpages. Although I am able to enter a new value ("Apple") when I save the page, it displays this error and removes my new value.

I believe this has something to do with the fact that the new value is not in the list of possible values, but I am not sure.

I found other [posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30019573/select-2-version-4-0-allow-user-to-enter-free-text) that suggested that I have to add the new value to the list of values before submitting the page. I tried this but it didn't work either.

I really like select2 and want to use it for all comboBoxes and ListBoxes, but there are many times where the use needs to enter new values.

Code for the comboBox:

```
<xp:comboBox id="model"
                                value="#{javascript:PCModel.model}" xp:key="field">
                                <xp:selectItems>
                                    <xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:viewScope.models}]]></xp:this.value>
                                </xp:selectItems>
                            </xp:comboBox>
```

And my script block:

```
<xp:scriptBlock id="scriptBlock1">
        <xp:this.value><![CDATA[$(document).ready(
function()
{
  x$("#{id:model}").select2({

  tags: true,
  createTag: function (params) {
    return {
      id: params.term,
      text: params.term,
      newOption: true
    }
  ;},

  templateResult: function (data) {
    var $result = $("<span></span>");
    $result.text(data.text);
    if (data.newOption) {
      $result.append(" <em>(new)</em>");
    }
    return $result;
  }
}
)
}
)]]></xp:this.value>
    </xp:scriptBlock>
```

Comment: I think you are mixing a solution that works in Select2 3.5.2 and below with a solution that works in 4.0+. Try to use Select2 4.0 (and not the old 2.4 version)

Comment: I kind of had a typo in which version of Select2 I am using. I am using Select2 4.0. I discovered that if I set the property "disableValidators" to true, then I do not get the error above that I am seeing. If the form passes validation then everything is fine. However, if it doesn't then the value goes back to "--Select A Model--". I am pretty sure that this is because the new value is not in the list of possible values. I save a post about this that said you had to add the new value to the list if you refresh. I need to add it to the viewScope.models and I believe I will be fine,.