# Add search term option to Select2 AJAX control

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-select2

I have a Select2 control working with AJAX - I can search a remote repository and select options from it just fine.  What I want to do though is add a new option to the control every time the AJAX search comes back to add that search term as a new option.

It shouldn't just add it when the search comes back empty, but with every search.

Ex: I search for `baseball` and my AJAX search returns the following results:

```
baseball fields
baseball games
baseball equipment
```

I want the Select2 dropdown to display:

```
baseball fields
baseball games
baseball equipment
baseball (Add As New)
```

Hoping this is as easy as just finding the correct Select2 option to hook into.  I can easily append an option in the `processResults` section of the `ajax` option, but can't figure out how to grab the actual term that was searched for.

EDIT: This problem is solvable in versions 3.5.2 and below, but I'm using 4.0.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Select2 dropdown but allow new values by user?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14577014/359284#30021059)

Answer (score 0):

I'll answer my own question with a sloppy hack that solves the problem for now... It seems this is easily solvable in Select2 3.5.x with the `createSearchChoice` option, but that was removed or restructured in v4.0 apparently.

In the `ajax` option, I was already using `url`, so I simply declared a global variable `lastSearch` that I updated before that url was returned

```
ajax: {
    url: function(params) {
        lastSearch = params.term;
        return "http://myapiurl.com/path/to/endpoint?search=" + params.term;
    }
}
```

Then in `processResults`, a quick check to see if the search term was empty, then simply append it to the data returned by my API

```
processResults: function(data) {
    if (lastSearch != "") {
        data.push({
            id: "-1",
            text: lastSearch + " (Add As New)"
        });
    }
    return { results: data }
}
```

Again, not the cleanest, but it gets the job done for now. I assume that since this functionality was available in older versions of Select2, it's just been moved somewhere else in v4.0, yet to be found.