# select2 as input text to add new options

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

I wonder if is there any way to use the select2 plugin to act like an input so I can save to db new values.

I mean I need an input that shows a list of match words but if the one I need is not in db leave the word in the input so I can store it.

Currently the input is just a search box so the word disappears.

Or is there another plugin that already does this?

Comment: have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14577014/select2-dropdown-but-allow-new-values-by-user

Comment: Also look at createSearchChoice in the docs http://select2.github.io/select2/

Comment: And this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25428361/dynamically-add-item-to-jquery-select2-control-that-uses-ajax

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what i was looking for!